# mhn install fails on linux ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu

I am trying to install mhn(modern honey network) on a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04

I got these errors.

````
Initializing` database, please be patient. This can take several minutes
+ python initdatabase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "initdatabase.py", line 5, in <module>
    create_clean_db()
  File "/opt/mhn/server/mhn/__init__.py", line 116, in create_clean_db
    db.create_all()
  File "/opt/mhn/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 963, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/opt/mhn/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 955, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/opt/mhn/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/opt/mhn/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, info, options)
  File "/opt/mhn/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 861, in apply_driver_hacks
    info.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, info.database)
AttributeError: can't set attribute```

how to fix this?
````

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is go into mhn/server/ and mod the requirements.txt doc, changing Flask-SQLAlchemy to 2.5.1, save out the file and run install with sudo. Should install just fine on 18.04 Ubuntu, only version personally tested on, mileage may very.